# Interpretting non-contiguous significance letters from Tukey HSD test in the multcomp package?

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc, tukey-hsd-test

I've only ever seen the compact letter display for Tukey's HSD give contiguous letter groupings but like in the following example this package is giving non-contiguous groupings (ie 'cde' is contiguous whereas 'a c' or 'c e' are not). Is there a useful interpretation of this?

I took this example from another question because it reproduces my curious results.

```
library(foreign)
yield <- read.dta("http://www.stata-press.com/data/r12/yield.dta")
tx <- with(yield, interaction(fertilizer, irrigation))
amod <- aov(yield ~ tx, data=yield)
library(agricolae)
HSD.test(amod, "tx", group=TRUE)
library(multcomp)
tuk <- glht(amod, linfct = mcp(tx = "Tukey"))
summary(tuk)          # standard display
tuk.cld <- cld(tuk)   # letter-based display
opar <- par(mai=c(1,1,1.5,1))
plot(tuk.cld)
par(opar)
par(opar)
```

[image: Tukey HSD compact letter display]

The difference between 'cde' and 'c e' is confusing, 'c e' seems to represent an impossible state in which the ends overlap with 'cde' but the middle doesn't. Does anyone know the correct interpretation of this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't have enough rep to make a comment so I have to 'answer': I think you should [put this in StackOverflow as it has to do with programming R, and not statistics](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297225/what-are-the-differences-between-stack-overflow-and-cross-validated). That said, if you look at the function code for plot.cld, you should be able to modify it to get what you want. ```
getAnywhere(plot.cld)
``` Also, it's unclear what you mean by contiguous/non-contiguous. To me, they look contiguous (a proceeds b, b proceeds c, etc...)

Comment: thanks, I'll repost it there. by contiguous I mean an unbroken line, ie abc or cde are contiguous letter groups, ac or df are not as there are letters missing between them

Comment: I would like this question to be opened again, I've edited it to fit this site

Comment: Too bad this question did not get answered. I am curious also. My initial interpretation is that the "CDE" group mean is distinct from "CE" because "CE" is significantly different from the "DF" group, but "CDE" is not. This is possible because the confidence interval of CDE is much wider both in the positive and negative direction than that of CE. So the assumption of homogeneity of variance may be violated here ... hence why OP has not observed this situation with noncontiguous letters very often. Am I off-base here?

Comment: I believe this answer misinterprets the intention of the question. The question is about how to interpret a particular outcome of a compact letter display (CLD), not about programming in R.

Comment: Also this question was in fact reposted on stackoverflow as requested but wasn't adequately answered there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138650/the-tukey-hsd-test-in-the-multcomp-package-gives-non-contiguous-significance-let